# How to create a function that takes an object and creates a new object where the values are key and the keys are values

Tags: javascript

I have to create a Scrabble Scorer for a class assignment. In this program I  have to create a function which takes the existing object "oldScoreKey" and create a newScoreKey where the the 26 letters are the keys and are lowercase. And the points for each letter are the values. Sounds easy enough but I keep having issues getting this part done.I wish I could just type up a new score key but the requirements for this assignment is making a function that does this for me. I not sure what I'm missing for my function to work. Any advice or solution with an explanation would be highly appreciated. I hope what I've stated make sense, and thanks in advance.

Throughout the last week, I've tried forEach(), and for...in loop statements. For the the lowercase part I've used .toLowerCase but kept getting a syntax error or it gets ignored.

```
  1: ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "L", "N", "R", "S", "T"],
  2: ["D", "G"],
  3: ["B", "C", "M", "P"],
  4: ["F", "H", "V", "W", "Y"],
  5: ["K"],
  8: ["J", "X"],
  10: ["Q", "Z"]
}

//My most recent attempt
function transform(oldScoreKey){
  for(let key in oldScoreKey){
    for(let i = 0; i < oldScoreKey[key].length; i++){
      for(let items in oldScoreKey[key][i]){
      let newScoreKey =+ oldScoreKey[items][keys];
      newScoreKey.toLowerCase();
      return newScoreKey;  
      }
    }
  }
}

//CLOSE BUT NOT RIGTH: SHows each letter on it's own line but the point value is on it's own line as well right below it.
 function transform(oldScoreKey){
   for(key in oldScoreKey){
     for(let i = 0; i < oldScoreKey[key].length; i++){
       let newScoreKey = {};
       newScoreKey += oldScoreKey[key][i];
      return newScoreKey[key];
    }
  }
 }



My expected results when returning newScoreKey is a new object which shows all 26 letters in lowercase as the keys and their point value as the vale.
Ex) a : 1,
    e : 1,
    and so on

Instead I'm getting undefined or all the letters each with their point values listed under them in the console screen.
```

Comment: You all are awesome. I've ran each of you all's suggested solutions and I love all of them. Thanks for also explaining your solutions. I'm realizing that when reading through the chapters in the course book and watching videos for better understanding I understand the basic concepts of what we go over. but when it comes to implementing those concepts into solving actual problems I have a hard time connecting the dots. Man I hope I get as good as you guys, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this; one method would be via the `.reduce()` function as shown:

```js
const start = {
  1: ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "L", "N", "R", "S", "T"],
  2: ["D", "G"],
  3: ["B", "C", "M", "P"],
  4: ["F", "H", "V", "W", "Y"],
  5: ["K"],
  8: ["J", "X"],
  10: ["Q", "Z"]
};

const transform = (oldScoreKey) => Object
  .entries(oldScoreKey) /* Transform object to array of key/value pairs */
  .reduce((result, [score, letters]) => { /* Transform as letter to score object */
  
    /* For each reduce iteration, we have a key/value pair from entries. Iterate
    the letters of each value array, and populate the result object with lower 
    case letter (key) on current score (value) */
    letters.forEach(letter => {
      result[letter.toLowerCase()] = score;
    });
    
    return result;
    
  }, {});

console.log(transform(start));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = {
    a: '1',
    b: '2'
}
const obj1 = {}
for (var item in obj) {
    obj1[obj[item]] = item;  
}
console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new object inside the function, and on each inner iteration, assign to a property of the object, then return the object at the very end of the function:

```js
const obj = {
  1: ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "L", "N", "R", "S", "T"],
  2: ["D", "G"],
  3: ["B", "C", "M", "P"],
  4: ["F", "H", "V", "W", "Y"],
  5: ["K"],
  8: ["J", "X"],
  10: ["Q", "Z"]
}

function transform(oldScoreKey){
  const newObj = {};
  for (const [letterValue, letterArr] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    for (const letter of letterArr) {
      newObj[letter.toLowerCase()] = letterValue;
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}

console.log(transform(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to take the keys of the input (using `Object.keys`) and loop over those. For each key (`score`), then loop over each letter. Assign that letter to a new object with the value of the `score`. Return the newly created object.

Here is this approach:

```js
const start = {
  1: ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "L", "N", "R", "S", "T"],
  2: ["D", "G"],
  3: ["B", "C", "M", "P"],
  4: ["F", "H", "V", "W", "Y"],
  5: ["K"],
  8: ["J", "X"],
  10: ["Q", "Z"]
};

function transform(oldScoreKey) {
  const result = {};

  Object.keys(oldScoreKey).forEach(score => {
    oldScoreKey[score].forEach(letter => {
      result[letter] = score;
    });
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(transform(start));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply

```
function transform(ob){
    var newObject = {};
    Object.keys(ob).forEach((key)=>{
        ob[key].forEach((character)=>{
            newObject[character] = key;
        })
    })
    return newObject;
}
```